# Error 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I'm trying to make a function that checks if a key for a book exists in the book table, and if it does, it determines the quantity of that book in the inventory table, and the number that have been sold from the purchased items table. When I try to run my current code it says "Result consisted of more than one row" every time I run it, no matter the value. I'm not clear on how else to tweak it.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION quantity_on_stock(
    book_key INT
)
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_books_recieved INT;
    DECLARE num_books_sold INT;
    DECLARE book_key_var INT;
    DECLARE book_inventory_key_var INT;

    SELECT book_key
    INTO book_key_var
    FROM books
    WHERE book_key = books.book_key;

    IF book_key = book_key_var THEN
        SELECT quantity INTO num_books_recieved FROM book_inventory bi WHERE book_key = bi.book_key;
        SELECT book_inventory_key INTO book_inventory_key_var FROM book_inventory bi WHERE book_key = bi.book_key;
        SELECT quantity INTO num_books_sold FROM purchase_items pi WHERE book_inventory_key_var = pi.book_inventory_key;
    END IF;

    RETURN (num_books_recieved - num_books_sold);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Book_key is a FK in the book inventory table. Book_inventory_key is a FK in the purchase_items table.

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  You are using `into` and presumably getting multiple rows.

Comment: I'm unsure how else to write without using INTO statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add LIMIT 1 to your query:

```
SELECT book_key
INTO book_key_var
FROM books
WHERE book_key = books.book_key
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic:

```
  SELECT quantity INTO num_books_recieved 
  FROM book_inventory bi
  WHERE book_key = bi.book_key;
```

Does not do what you think.  The first `book_key` refers to the columns as well -- columns are matched before variables.

So, it is really:

```
  SELECT quantity INTO num_books_recieved 
  FROM book_inventory bi
  WHERE bi.book_key = bi.book_key;
```

I would suggest renaming the variables to something that doesn't conflict with the column names.